# inputmask removing second zero after decimal on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using an [input mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) for a currency input field (USD). I'm also using [dinero.js](https://sarahdayan.github.io/dinero.js) to handle dealing with floating point numbers, which requires an integer be passed to it. The problem is, when a user clicks on the input field, the second zero after the decimal point is being removed by the input mask, which is causing the form values to be wrong when converting to an integer.

This is my input mask:

```
 $('body').on('focus', 'input.money', function(){
        $(this).inputmask("numeric", {
            radixPoint: ".",
            groupSeparator: ",",
            digits: 2,
            autoGroup: true,
            prefix: '$',
            oncleared: function () { $(this).val(''); }
        });
    });
```

When the form is submitted, I'm stripping the decimal point and just passing that to my ajax function, and if there's not a decimal, I'm multiplying by 100 and passing it.

so in the instance described above, if the input is pre-populated with $100.00 on page load, and then I click on it, it becomes $100.0. Then if I were to just backspace and enter $10, it keeps the .0 value so the entered value is $10.0.

On form submission, this gets the decimal stripped and the value becomes an integer value of 100, which then gets incorrectly set as a $10.00 value.

Hopefully that makes sense. I plan on adding form validation to ensure that there are 2 places after the decimal before the form is submitted, but it also bothers me from a UX perspective. I feel like I've used this plugin in the past and it worked really well, so I feel like I'm messing something up here.

To summarize: If the value is populated with $100.00 on page load, when the field gets focus, i want the value to stay $100.00, not change to $100.0.

Here's how I'm stripping the decimal from the values. I am also using this for values coming out of the DB which is why I'm also stripping out `$` and `,`.

```
function strip(value) {
    if(value.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      return parseInt(value.replace('$','').replace(',','').replace('.','')) || 0;
    } else {
      return parseInt(value.replace('$','').replace(',','')) * 100 || 0;
    }

  }
```

Comment: how are you stripping the decimal off?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I added it to the question.

Comment: it was removing the other zero even before I was using the "strip" function.

Comment: if its strictly american english...id remove the commas...then parse as a float and truncate the number...rather than the multiplication by 100

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the 2 decimals with the mask:

```
alias: 'decimal',
mask: "99[.99]"
```

Sounds like the dinero.js is making a conflict. Also, for the submission, try the [unmaskedvalue](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#unmaskedvalue) method on your value:

```
var value = $(selector).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
```

Or if you decided not to use ajax to submit, you can add [removeMaskOnSubmit](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#removemaskonsubmit) to the data-inputmask attribute.